# nested IF, AND, OR function compare and give result excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

Need help with this function.

```
=IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks M")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks L")),1,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks XL")),2,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks S")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),3,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),4,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Super")),5,IF(AND($F5="Miks M",OR($G5="Prica Plus")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Prica Plus")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks S")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks M")),1,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks L")),2,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks XL")),3,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),4,IF(AND($F5="Miks S",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),5,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Prica Plus")),0,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks S")),1,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks M")),2,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks L")),3,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks XL")),4,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),5,IF(AND($F5="Prica Plus",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),6,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Prica plus")),-3,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks S")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks M")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks L")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks XL")),1,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),2,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),3,IF(AND($F5="Miks L",OR($G5="Super")),4,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Prica plus")),-4,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks S")),-3,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks M")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks L")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks XL")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),1,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),2,IF(AND($F5="Miks xL",OR($G5="Super")),3,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Prica plus")),-5,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks S")),-4,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks M")),-3,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks L")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks XL")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks XL Plus",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),1,IF(AND($F5="Miks xL Plus",OR($G5="Super")),2,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Prica plus")),-6,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks S")),-5,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks M")),-4,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks L")),-3,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks XL")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Miks XXL",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),0,IF(AND($F5="Miks xXL",OR($G5="Super")),1,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Prica plus")),-7,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks S")),-6,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks M")),-5,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks L")),-4,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks XL")),-3,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks XL PLUS")),-2,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Miks XXL")),-1,IF(AND($F5="Super",OR($G5="Super")),0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Is there any chance to this function become shorter and simpler?
For now its working perfect but if it can be shorter it would be much better.
If cell F5 is Miks M and cell G5 is Miks M write 0 in H5 if G5 is Miks L write 1 in H5 and soo on.

Comment: ***Surely*** you don't expect us to actually decipher that!? Break it down into a much simpler example that we can more easily digest and provide a solution to... and then extend the solution we give you to cover the whole formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=MATCH(G5,{"Prica Plus","Miks S","Miks M","Miks L","Miks XL","Miks XL Plus","Miks XXL","Super"},0)-MATCH(F5,{"Prica Plus","Miks S","Miks M","Miks L","Miks XL","Miks XL Plus","Miks XXL","Super"},0)
```

Above formula can be broken down in two parts. Firstly, matching `Cell G5` to your values

```
=MATCH(G5,{"Prica Plus","Miks S","Miks M","Miks L","Miks XL","Miks XL Plus","Miks XXL","Super"},0)
```

Secondly, matching `Cell H5` to your values

```
=MATCH(F5,{"Prica Plus","Miks S","Miks M","Miks L","Miks XL","Miks XL Plus","Miks XXL","Super"},0)
```

then subtracting both values.

Answer (score 3):

Create a table with your values in like this:

[image]

Then a simple `SUMIFS` formula will do the rest for you:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$4,$A$1:$A$4,$F5,$B$1:$B$4,$G5)
```

---

*Another possible solution:*

If you are just trying to see how the sizes are different you could create a much simpler ordered table like this:

```
Prica Plus
S
M
L
XL
XL PLUS
XXL
Super
```

And use a formula like this:

```
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($G5,"Miks ",""),$A$1:$A$8,0)-MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($F5,"Miks ",""),$A$1:$A$8,0)
```

Where the table above is in `A1:A8`. This formula removes "Miks " from the values so it is just comparing the sizes. More specifically, it is returning the difference in positions of the two sizes in the table.

Comment: Thanks CallumDA your solution works for me but there is only one thing, when u have Miks M in value 1 and u have empty value 2 u got result 0. Can that be something else?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nightmare...
Anyhow, if you can use VBA, try to rewrite the whole formula to something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TryMe() As String

    Select Case True
        Case Range("F5") = "Miks M" Or Range("G5") = "Miks M"
            TryMe = "MiksM"
        Case Range("F5") = "MiksL" Or Range("G5") = "MiksL"
            TryMe = "MiksL"
        Case Else
            TryMe = "Something Else"
    End Select

End Function
```

Then you would only write `=TryMe` and you would be getting the result.

Comment: How can you even begin to offer a solution to this? Honestly though, VBA seems quite unnecessary and given OP clearly needs guidance with some simple worksheet formulas, I doubt they would have any idea what to do with this solution.

Comment: @CallumDA - 62 ifs seems like a real pain. Thus, I thought that VBA may be useful here.